# File size restriction on .exe python tkinter program?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tkinter, exe, filesize

I have a .py program that works perfectly once run in the console or in an IDE. However, once I convert the program to an .exe using cx_Freeze, it only works with smaller csv files loaded in to do it's function on. It force closes the whole .exe program once the file gets too large, with no error messages prompted at all.

Is there a file size restriction on maybe the memory that an .exe python program can handle when loading in such a file while running? And if so, is there any way to bypass it somehow on Windows?

Comment: The problem again, is when I run the .exe file, the program boots up properly it seems, but will force close if I try to load in larger csv files.

Comment: Do some experiments to quantify the upper limit. This value may help to narrow the range of possible problems. My guess would be that you're building a 32-bit executable, which limits the amount of virtual memory available and maximum sequence/array length. But that's only a factor if we're talking about hundreds of megabytes or multi-gigabyte data sets, depending on how the data is handled.

Comment: The program will need to handle 500MB+ csv files. My testing so far has determined that a 30MB csv file is already too big. Would building a 64-bit executable eliminate this problem? And if so, how do you indicate to cx_Freeze you'd like to use 64-bit?